# Angular 5 conact string only if field exists in html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to concat two fields but the problem is in some cases the second field doesn't exist. In the below code `group.GroupDescription` field is not present in some entires. Is there any way to concat both fields only if second field `group.GroupDescription`exists.

**Note** - I also tried safe navigation operator but it displays null if value is not present.

Thanks in adavnce

```
         <select
            [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup"
            class="form-control"
            (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
          >
            <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Select</option>

            <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [ngValue]="group">{{
              group.GroupName.S + ' - ' + group.GroupDescription?.S
            }}</option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast and simple solution could be:

```js
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Select</option>

    <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [ngValue]="group">
        {{
            group.GroupName.S + (group.GroupDescription ? " - " + group.GroupDescription.S : '')
        }}
    </option>
</select>
```

but I suggest you to pre-build the string somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="group.GroupDescription">
  {{group.GroupName.S + ' - ' + group.GroupDescription.S}}
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!group.GroupDescription">
  {{group.GroupName.S}}
</ng-container>
```